# When to call dispose on global streams and stream controllers in Flutter App

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-stream

I have couple of streams which are to be used across all the flutter screens. I initialise them before first screen and as and when needed. But now if I don't dispose them, since they are to used as long as user is using the application will they get automatically disposed if user kills the application.

Will this change the iOS and Android app background behaviour, if user just kept the app in background ?